# Sudden overflow with float/clear

Tags: css

I'm trying to style a page without the common grid systems using float and clear. The page should use the full viewport for both width and height. The below setup works fine, unless I start resizing the viewport. Once I move the viewport, the navigation and content section suddenly start to overlap, with the content being rendered below the navigation.

Is there something wrong with my approach or should I not use `vh` and `vw` when users are likely to resize the viewport?

The setup is meant to be conceivably simple:

- A header bar with a height of 40px.
- A side navigation section with a width of 20vw
- A content section with a width of 80 vw - some margins.
- The navigation and content sections are meant to have a min height to fill the viewport.

Sizes like `79.99vw` and `99.9vh` were introduced to avoid any rounding issues. I have also tried `80vw` and `100vh` respectively.

My template looks like this:

```
<div class="dashboard-wrapper">
  <header class="header-bar">
    <h1 class="bar-title">Brand Logo</h1>
    <button class="logout-button">Log out</button>
  </header>
  <section class="side-bar">
    <nav role="navigation" class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li>Navigation One</li>
        <li>Navigation Two</li>
        <li>Navigation Three</li>
        <li>Navigation Four</li>
        <li>Navigation Five</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
  <section class="content">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis ...</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
.dashboard-wrapper {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.dashboard-wrapper header.header-bar {
  float: top;
  height: 40px;
}
.dashboard-wrapper header.header-bar h1 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  float: left;
}
.dashboard-wrapper header.header-bar button {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 0;
  float: right;
}
.dashboard-wrapper section.side-bar {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 20vw;
  min-height: calc(99.9vh - 40px - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  background: white;
}
.dashboard-wrapper section.content {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(79.99vw - 30px);
  min-height: calc(99.9vh - 40px - 20px);
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  background: white;
}
```

This was so far only tested in Chrome on Windows.

Comment: `float:top` does not exist...there's one thing to fix.

Comment: Also I'm not sure mixing `viewport units` and `px` is a good idea.

Comment: I have removed the `float:top` and also tried to replace all the px units with  1vh/vw per 10 px, This did not fix the issue I have. It's also quite ugly as the px units are used for margins and hence substituting them with viewport sizes means they change as you resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Removed  invalid `float:top`,
- added clearfix class : `.cf` to clear `float`s
- added `box-sizing:border-box` just in case you might use `padding`
- switched `width` using `vw` units for `%` units to get rounded values when using `calc` and to get consistent result across devices.
- a few other small things.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.dashboard-wrapper header.header-bar {
  height: 40px;
  /*demo*/
  background: green
}
.dashboard-wrapper header.header-bar h1 {
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  float: left;
}
.dashboard-wrapper header.header-bar button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  border: 0;
  float: right;
}
.dashboard-wrapper section.side-bar {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}
.dashboard-wrapper section.content {
  float: left;
  width: calc(80% - 30px);
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  background: lightblue;
}
footer {
 background:orange;
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-wrapper">
  <header class="header-bar cf">
    <h1 class="bar-title">Brand Logo</h1>
    <button class="logout-button">Log out</button>
  </header>
  <div class="main-wrapper cf">
    <section class="side-bar">
      <nav role="navigation" class="sidebar">
        <ul>
          <li>Navigation One</li>
          <li>Navigation Two</li>
          <li>Navigation Three</li>
          <li>Navigation Four</li>
          <li>Navigation Five</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </section>
    <section class="content">
      <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis ...</p>
    </section>
  </div>
  <footer>
    Lorem Ipsum ed ut perspiciatis ...
  </footer>
</div>
```